# Issue with Conferencing

Tags: node.js, twilio

On our application we have agents making outbound calls. All inbound and outbound calls are converted to conferences so we can easily place calls on hold, transfer calls, and moderate calls.

8 times out of 10 the following code works flawlessly

This is part of our index.js file. The conference function is called when we are making our outbound calls.

### Index.js

```
function conference(sid1, sid2, i, agent){
 if(i < 240){
  setTimeout(function(){
   i++;
   client.calls(sid2).get(function(err, call) {
     if(call.status == 'in-progress'){
        client.calls(sid2).update({
          url:"https://" + config.socket + "/inbound/trans/agent/" + agent,
          method: "POST"
        }, function(err, call) {
          s1 = true;
          if(err){console.log("Error 299: "); console.log(err)};
        });
        console.log("SID 2: " + sid2);
        client.calls(sid1).update({
          url:"https://" + config.socket + "/inbound/trans/agent/" + agent,
          method: "POST"
        }, function(err, call) {
          s2 = true;
          if(err){console.log("Error 299: "); console.log(err)};
        });


      }else if(call.status == 'completed'){

      }else{
        conference(sid1, sid2, i, agent);
      }
    });

  }, 1000);


}

}

router.post('/inbound/trans/agent/:agent', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals = {
   name: req.params.agent,
  }
  res.render('twilio/connect');
  });
```

twilio/connect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference record="record-from-start" startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="true">
        {{name}}
     </Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Now as I have said 8/10 times this works perfectly. now on the other 2/10 times the outbound call which is identified by sid1 just drops when answered.

In testing we have called the same cell phone 10 times and twice in those 10 times when answering the call just drops.

When this drop happens the logs show nothing unusual. No activity initiated by us.

It just goes from calling the twilio/connect and playing music, to our /callback phase for calls which are ended.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'd get in contact with help@twilio.com with this issue if I were you. If you could provide Call SIDs for successful and unsuccessful calls that will help too.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it was on my end. I have console print statements I excluded here for brevity sake. When I have the issue only one of the statements is getting called. Then the program seems to just skip the other statement and the call disconnects. I will contact Help just to see but will leave this open for now to see if anyone else has come across this before